# TensorFlow estimator export_saved_model function restore variables failed when I add new variable to graph

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow-estimator

when i use estimator export_saved_model function to get model pb file, encountered a error which is as below:

ValueError: Could not load all requested variables from checkpoint. Please make sure your model_fn does not expect variables that were not saved in the checkpoint.

Encountered error with mode `infer` while restoring checkpoint from: `....../ckpt/model.ckpt-1200`. Full Traceback:

Restoring from checkpoint failed. This is most likely due to a Variable name or other graph key that is missing from the checkpoint. Please ensure that you have not altered the graph expected based on the checkpoint. Original error ......(skip)

for some reason，i need to restore part of variables, and add new variables. Does anyone has any suggestions? How can I make it work when i using export_saved_model function?